# Build code by using Concatenation?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way i can create code build code by using Concatenation in Android studio/eclipse?

In other words i have 2 sets of strings one for each country i am dealing with ZA and KE. They have 2 different EULA's.

So i would like to pull the string related to the respective country.

```
String message = mContext.getString(R.string.eula_string_za);
```

above is an example of the output code. is there someway i can go about "creating" that based on If statements?

```
String str = "mContext.getString(R.string.eula_string_";
if (something = "ZA") {
    str += "za);";
} else {
    str += "ke);";
}
```

so if the country selected is ZA then the output code should be

```
mContext.getString(R.string.eula_string_za);
```

and if its KE it should be

```
mContext.getString(R.string.eula_string_ke);
```

and then the result will then pull the correct string from strings.xml?

Answer (score 5):

Java is a compiled code, not an executed one,you can't write code this way like in an interpreted language.

The best way to manage different languages in android is to use a string.xml file for each language.
 Take a look at this tutorial, it will help you a lot :

[Supporting different languages in android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go this route you could try to use reflection. Have a look at [`Class.getField(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-) if you want to use reflection.

Instead of first building a code string using a `if` statement you can also use the same `if` statement to find the correct string:

```
String str;
if (something.equals("ZA")) {
    str = mContext.getString(R.string.eula_string_za);
} else {
    str = mContext.getString(R.string.eula_string_ke);
}
```

Note that your condition `something = "ZA"` does not do what you think it does: It assigns `something` the string `"ZA"` and then evaluates itself to `"ZA"`, so this would not even compile. The correct way would be `something == "ZA"`, but even this [does not work in the general case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1347968). You need to use [`String.equals(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Some even argue you should use it the other way around (i.e. `"ZA".equals(something)`) to avoid a `NullPointerException`…

Another possibility would be to first build a `Map` from county to the corresponding string ID for all the EULAs you have and then asking the `Map` to return the correct one.

But probably the cleanest solution would be to use Androids built in mechanism, [as hkN suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29966170/1347968).

Comment: thanks, its not based on languages, its based on the countries "policies" that the terms and conditions are different(dont know the legality of it, i just make the app lol)